# How to get parent items with BeautifulSoup4?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, strip-tags

I'm getting soup using this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find("tbody").find_all("tr")
```

And then soup object contains multiple similar tr> objects just like this:

```
<tr>
<td class="table">115</td>
<td>204</td>
<td><div><span class="flag-icon"></span>  United States <span> NY </span></div></td>
<td>brown</td>
<td>up</td>
<td class="table">groove</td>
</tr>
```

So, my goal is - to get stripped text data from just 1,2,4  and put them together to small list. Like this:

```
[115, 204, 'brown']
```

And after I got all the small lists from all , I have to add all of them to big list. Like this:

```
[[115, 204, 'brown'], [32, 12, 'red'] ... [42, 87, 'yellow']]
```

To be honest, I did it using two for loops, and sliced needed small list items to append a big list. But I assume, there is much better and simplier way to do that.

Maybe you have some ideas how to use powerful abilities of BeautifulSoup in my case?

Comment: can you elaborate, what do you mean by small list and big list? Can you paste rest of the code for the logic?

Comment: @nandal Thank you, I've just updated my post with examples.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:-

```
rows = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml').find("tbody").find_all("tr")
bigList = []
for row in rows:
    tds = row.find_all("td")
    bigList.append([tds[0].text, tds[1].text, tds[3].text])
```

Comment: Thank you very much, Nandal. Your solution is better than my. Only 1 loop instead 2, no additional variable and there is no need in deleting of items in small lists.